# How to fix "Error establishing database connection"

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Pretty much every single Wordpress site I've set up with MySQL, sooner or later gives the message `Error establishing database connection`.

Restarting MySQL fixes it. Until it gets to a certain point, where rebooting the whole server is required, as it just hangs trying to restart it.

This has been various versions of Wordpress, on various versions of Linux.

What is it causing this, and what's the cure?

Comment: If you check the logs (MySQL ,apache , maybe the server as well) I am pretty sure you will find the answers

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the number of open connections using - `SHOW STATUS WHERE` variable_name `= 'Threads_connected';`. You can use `SHOW processlist` to get the number of running process which will show you the number of users. Mostly it is because the credentials are incorrect or the number of open connections have reached the maximum.

Comment: Just showing as '1'

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error-code